# LINQ to SQL return statement

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In a project i have a LINQ to SQL class which is OrderingSystem.dbml. I have the following code and in the select statement i want to retrieve only some of the rows from each table(Products - Categories). But of course the return statement that i have right now it is not correct. What is the correct return statement to use?? Thanks in advance

```
    OrderingSystemDataContext database = new OrderingSystemDataContext();

    public List<Product> GetProductsByCategoryID(int CategoryID)
    {
        var result = from p in database.Products
        join c in database.Categories
        on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
        where p.CategoryID == CategoryID
        select new { p.ProductName, p.ProductPrice, p.ProductDescription, c.CategoryName };

        //This is not working
        return result.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: @DanielA.White The exact error from Visual Studio is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<OrderingSystemWebServices.Product>'"

Comment: Do you even need a where clause given you're joining on those same columns? Also in the where clause that 2nd CategoryID looks ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

On the select new you have to specify the type if you then want to retrieve a list of products, right now it creates an anonymous type. Try changing with :

```
OrderingSystemDataContext database = new OrderingSystemDataContext();

public List<Product> GetProductsByCategoryID(int CategoryID)
{
    var result = from p in database.Products
    join c in database.Categories
    on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
    where p.CategoryID == CategoryID
    //Assuming that these are the names of your properties
    select new Product(){ProductName = p.ProductName, ProductPrice = p.ProductPrice, ProductDescription = p.ProductDescription, CategoryName = c.CategoryName };

    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I receive no errors while building the project but when i try to invoke the wcf service it says this: Explicit construction of entity type 'OrderingSystemWebServices.Product' in query is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is Product but your query result uses an anonymous type.

Change this line:

```
select new { p.ProductName, p.ProductPrice, p.ProductDescription, c.CategoryName };
```

to something like this:

```
select new Product { Name = p.ProductName, Price = p.ProductPrice, Description = p.ProductDescription, Category = c.CategoryName };
```

EDIT:

Try just replacing it with:

```
select p;
```

Comment: I receive no errors while building the project but when i try to invoke the wcf service it says this: Explicit construction of entity type 'OrderingSystemWebServices.Product' in query is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in the LINQ expression, you did a `select new { }` which creates an anonymous object, while your method returns a List of `Product`. You should change the `select` statement so it becomes `select new Product() { ProductName = p.ProductName, ...` the rest depends on the structure of your `Product` class.

Answer (score 0):

By using the "select new" LINQ operation, you are creating an anonymous type. You can access the properties of that anonymous type within the current scope of the objects' creation, but you cannot return that anonymous type using any kind of recognizable type. You have two options:

1. Create a new class (e.g. Product) and create instances of that type as part of your select statement (as the other answers instruct)
2. Return the collection as `List<object>`. If you do this, you can still retrieve values from the objects, but you will need to do so via reflection. This can be quite valid if you are using the collection as the data source in a data binding scenario.